# Как задать path в terminal в visual-studio-code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Использую VS code в Windows 10, терминал powershell

Есть ряд программ, находящихся в директории проекта, например node_modules/.bin
Для того чтобы их просто вызывать нужно добавить путь в path так:

$env:Path+=";.\node_modules.bin"

Вопрос.
Каждый раз давать такую команду неудобно.

Я думаю что где в недрах VS есть настройки, которые позволяют задать дополнения к PATH

Подскажите пожалуйста как в settings записать что некоторые пути будут добавляться к имеющемуся системному PATH ?

Comment: именно для node можно использовать npx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Git Bash и стандартного cmd у меня работает так:

Локальные настройки проекта:

*.vscode\settings.json*

```
{
  "terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
    "PATH": "${env:PATH};${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\.bin"
  }
}
```

... перезапускаем терминал